# Responding to Multiple Command Line Prompts

Tags: command, exe, dos

I have an exe that runs though Windows Console and prompts for responses for three questions.  I created a batch file to contain criteria and would like to automate all three responses to the questions so selecting the bat file runs the data within the batch file.

I need to pass the following criteria
1)machine name 
(Enter)
2)password
(Enter)
3)backup
(Enter)

I tried "machinename| exe" and it runs fine, and then brings up the prompt for 2)'s answer.  I would like answer all three prompts and then run the exe.

Comment: Ouch. That seems a harsh down vote for a new user. I agree the question could be improved, but I had no problem understanding it, and the question is of higher quality than many other first time posters.

Comment: I suspect you are actually running your program within a Windows console, which is ***not*** DOS. It looks similar, but the CMD.EXE console is not DOS.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I will edit the question.  And thank you for recognizing my neubness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all inputs are executed via stdin, then either a pipe or redirection should work for all three inputs.

The simplest method is to create a temporary response file and use redirection.

```
@echo off
>response.tmp (
  echo machinename
  echo password
  echo backup
)
<response.tmp prog.exe
del response.tmp
```

It would seem it would be easy to use a pipe and get rid of the temp file

```
(echo machinename&echo password&echo backup)|prog.exe
```

But there is one problem - the parser inserts a space before each `&` and the `)`. This will probably break things.

Note that each side of the pipe is executed via `cmd /c`, so each side is parsed twice. It is the initial pipe parser that inserts the unwanted space.

The simplest way I have found to prevent the extra space is to delay the appearance of the `&` so that the parser initially thinks the entire left side is a single ECHO command.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "+=&"
echo machinename%%+%%echo password%%+%%echo backup|prog.exe
```

**EDIT**

The fact that your program hangs at the password prompt implies that the password is read directly from the console, and not via stdin. In this case, you will need something like the [freeware AutoIT utility](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. The exe runs, and the machine name is getting passed, but it continues to pause on the prompt for the password (question 2).

Comment: @Heat - The password must not be read from stdin. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: dbenham-That seems to be what I need.  Thanks again for your time.